# disable spring boot 2 default metrics

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have spring boot 2 REST application, with spring actuator enabled. by default spring generates a number of metrics (*jvm, cpu, memory, etc*) in `/metrics` endpoint. Apart from this I have used Micrometer APIs to create custom metrics. So far its been working really well.

Now, I have a requirement to generate only my custom metrics, but disable all the default metrics that spring provides. Note that I **do not** want to disable `/metrics` endpoint, but I want to disable only the default metrics.

Is this possible directly/indirectly now?

Thanks for any opinions and suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like most things in Spring Boot, the default metrics are configured via various auto-configuration classes. To disable the default metrics, exclude their auto-configuration classes using the `exclude` attribute on `@SpringBootApplication`. To see what auto-configurations are involved, you can launch your app with `--debug` or take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics).

Answer (score 11):

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = { 
        CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.class, 
        TomcatMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
        SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class, 
        SystemMetricsAutoConfiguration.class 
    }
)
```

You need to exclude all the metrics auto configuration classes which are responsible for the default metrics in Spring Boot.

You can find all the metrics auto configuration classes here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.1.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I did to solve this issue in my code was to enable the 'Conditions Evaluation Report'. Setting the property `debug=true` in your `application.properties` file is sufficient. You should see something like the below in your logs. Just search this block for 'Metric' to find mentions of metrics-related classes.

```
2021-05-04T11:35:29.001-0300|DEBUG tionEvaluationReportLoggingListener[ 126] - 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   AopAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.aop.auto=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)

   ...
```

Next, you'll want to disable any auto-configured metrics classes that are not useful to you. You can do this by adding some attribute values to your `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

This is what I did in my application code:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    exclude = {
            CompositeMeterRegistryAutoConfiguration.class,
            JvmMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
            DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
            LogbackMetricsAutoConfiguration.class,
            HttpClientMetricsAutoConfiguration.class
    }
)
```

Finally, if there is an auto-configured metrics class that publishes some metrics values you want to keep, but others that you do not want, then you can disable individual metrics. This is easy if you are using an `application.yaml` file. Below is an example from my code:

```
management:
  metrics:
    # Disable Spring Boot auto-configuration of metrics meter registries
    use-global-registry: false
    enable:
      jvm:
        # garbage collection, buffer, threads and classes metrics are not useful to us
        gc: false
        buffer: false
        classes: false
        threads: false
      process:
        # process start time is useless
        start:
          time: false
      # system CPU metrics are useless for ECS tasks (we only care about 'process' metrics)
      system:
        cpu: false
    export:
      # Disable default in-memory metrics meter registry
      simple:
        enabled: false
      # Publish metrics to AWS Cloudwatch, using the largest submission batch size that AWS supports
      cloudwatch:
        namespace: /my/metrics/namespace
        batchSize: 20
```

You can do the same with an `application.properties` file. It will just be more verbose.

There is also support for writing custom 'filter' classes that give you finer grained control than the properties/yaml file approach above. I haven't used it, but I mention it here for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Exclude metrics wired by `MetricsAutoConfiguration.class` like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = MetricsAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score -1):

In theory, it should be possible to extend org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint and expose only the information that you want to expose.

However, I would suggest to always define a new endpoint to handle your specific use case.
In that case, you will not be bound to Spring libraries too tightly.